# Controlling for individual in nlme when most individuals only measured once

Tags: random-effects-model, assumptions, lme4-nlme

I am trying to model **growth** using nlme for a number of individuals over four time periods. My question is, did growth differ over time? Some individuals were measured twice or more, perhaps as a young individual then again as an adult, or twice as a young individual, etc. I want to let my model know data points for the same individual might be correlated. I've fit a model and I'm trying to assess whether the residuals indicate deviance from the assumptions - there is some indication that they do.

80% of individuals were measured only once,
16 % of individuals were measured twice, and
4 % of individuals were measured 3-5 times.

**I have two questions:**

1) Is my specification of random effects appropriate when only a few individuals are measured more than once? I have a feeling it's a bit over-kill - **what are my alternatives?**

2) **How can I model the heteroscedasticity in the residuals if only a few individuals are measured more than once?** (Please note - I'm only concerned about the linear trend, not variance, in the residuals, since in my actual models the variance is OK). Or - another question - when should one be worried about a linear trend in residuals vs fitted values, especially if the linear trend is weak (e.g. correlation of 0.12, with 600 data points).

*(Sample data at the bottom of this post - using only two time periods to simplify)*

```
# Get libraries and define growth function
library(nlme)

# Here, "Linf" is the asymptote, "K" is the slope, 
# and "t0" is the theoretical size at Age "0"

LVB = function(t, Linf, K, t0) {
if (length(Linf) == 3) {
        K <- Linf[[2]]
        t0 <- Linf[[3]]
        Linf <- Linf[[1]]}
Linf*(1-exp(-K*(t-t0))) }

# Define model, controlling for individual in random effects 
mod <- nlme(Measure~LVB(capAge,Linf, K, t0),data=exdf,
                fixed = list(Linf~Time, K~1, t0~Time),
                random = Linf+K~1,
                start  = list(fixed= c(34, 0, 
                                       0.7,  
                                       -0.65, 0)))
# Take a look at it
summary(mod)  # Ok, not much difference between Time periods
pairs(mod)
```

The correlation here (below) bothers me - it's worse for some of my "real" models. HOWEVER - maybe I shouldn't worry. Because there are so many individuals only measured once, the random effects likely drift towards the fixed effect. It may be better to "keep the random effects maximal" (Mirman, 2014 - Growth Curve Analysis and Visualization using R) and let them account for some variation - which will make the SE of the fixed effects more appropriate (larger).

[image: pairs plot]

```
fitvals = fitted(mod)
res = residuals(mod)
rand = random.effects(mod)

std.res = res / sd(res)
qqnorm(std.res, main = "standardized residuals")
```

These look ok

[image: fixed qqnorm]

```
std.rand = rand[[1]] / sd(rand[[1]])
qqnorm(std.rand, main = "standardized random effects")
```

These are also ok-ish

[image: random qqnorm]

```
plot(fitvals, abs(std.res))
summary(lm(abs(std.res) ~ fitvals)) ## 
abline(lm(abs(std.res) ~ fitvals))
```

Hm, there is a *significant* pattern here - **how to fix?**

[image: fitted vs residuals]

```
# Plot it
plot(exdf$capAge[exdf$capAge > 2], exdf$Measure[exdf$capAge > 2], col = exdf$Time, pch = 16)
curve(LVB(x, 34.6, 0.6, -1), col = "black", add = TRUE)
curve(LVB(x, 34.7, 0.6, -0.9), col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

The model looks like this:

[image: raw data and model lines]

```
exdf <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(10L, 54L, 163L, 132L, 141L, 116L, 
37L, 36L, 142L, 176L, 58L, 71L, 15L, 1L, 177L, 111L, 40L, 53L, 
180L, 174L, 101L, 153L, 80L, 122L, 148L, 108L, 17L, 135L, 30L, 
166L, 136L, 154L, 50L, 68L, 87L, 155L, 78L, 44L, 2L, 26L, 112L, 
129L, 24L, 31L, 156L, 157L, 123L, 12L, 167L, 57L, 72L, 41L, 19L, 
130L, 168L, 113L, 137L, 138L, 158L, 159L, 61L, 27L, 35L, 81L, 
124L, 88L, 87L, 102L, 139L, 7L, 160L, 73L, 172L, 114L, 131L, 
14L, 149L, 103L, 169L, 3L, 69L, 70L, 161L, 32L, 125L, 55L, 28L, 
162L, 33L, 140L, 47L, 60L, 115L, 95L, 175L, 39L, 34L, 83L, 74L, 
29L, 38L, 96L, 42L, 66L, 135L, 89L, 79L, 109L, 52L, 63L, 80L, 
104L, 150L, 83L, 155L, 82L, 143L, 62L, 105L, 48L, 99L, 117L, 
75L, 84L, 65L, 11L, 170L, 18L, 126L, 106L, 118L, 40L, 5L, 97L, 
157L, 164L, 144L, 64L, 90L, 149L, 16L, 156L, 67L, 91L, 127L, 
77L, 98L, 126L, 173L, 59L, 25L, 171L, 100L, 51L, 163L, 127L, 
156L, 104L, 172L, 85L, 128L, 110L, 20L, 49L, 92L, 151L, 93L, 
83L, 43L, 133L, 119L, 145L, 94L, 120L, 179L, 146L, 45L, 76L, 
134L, 121L, 86L, 13L, 6L, 131L, 147L, 22L, 4L, 152L, 132L, 107L, 
23L, 8L, 181L, 139L, 178L, 165L, 9L, 56L, 46L, 21L), .Label = c("I-14", 
"I-39", "I-79", "I-170", "I-127", "I-167", "I-69", "I-174", "I-178", 
"I-01", "I-121", "I-48", "I-166", "I-75", "I-13", "I-133", "I-27", 
"I-123", "I-53", "I-148", "I-181", "I-169", "I-173", "I-43", 
"I-141", "I-40", "I-62", "I-86", "I-99", "I-29", "I-44", "I-83", 
"I-88", "I-96", "I-63", "I-08", "I-07", "I-100", "I-95", "I-17", 
"I-52", "I-102", "I-153", "I-38", "I-161", "I-180", "I-90", "I-115", 
"I-149", "I-33", "I-144", "I-107", "I-18", "I-02", "I-85", "I-179", 
"I-50", "I-11", "I-140", "I-91", "I-61", "I-113", "I-108", "I-131", 
"I-120", "I-103", "I-134", "I-34", "I-80", "I-81", "I-12", "I-51", 
"I-71", "I-98", "I-118", "I-162", "I-137", "I-37", "I-105", "I-23", 
"I-64", "I-111", "I-97", "I-119", "I-145", "I-165", "I-35", "I-66", 
"I-104", "I-132", "I-135", "I-150", "I-152", "I-157", "I-93", 
"I-101", "I-128", "I-138", "I-116", "I-143", "I-21", "I-67", 
"I-77", "I-109", "I-114", "I-125", "I-172", "I-26", "I-106", 
"I-147", "I-16", "I-41", "I-56", "I-73", "I-92", "I-06", "I-117", 
"I-126", "I-155", "I-158", "I-164", "I-24", "I-47", "I-65", "I-84", 
"I-124", "I-136", "I-146", "I-42", "I-54", "I-74", "I-04", "I-154", 
"I-163", "I-28", "I-31", "I-57", "I-58", "I-68", "I-89", "I-05", 
"I-09", "I-112", "I-130", "I-156", "I-160", "I-168", "I-25", 
"I-76", "I-110", "I-151", "I-171", "I-22", "I-32", "I-36", "I-45", 
"I-46", "I-59", "I-60", "I-70", "I-82", "I-87", "I-03", "I-129", 
"I-177", "I-30", "I-49", "I-55", "I-78", "I-122", "I-142", "I-72", 
"I-139", "I-20", "I-94", "I-10", "I-15", "I-176", "I-159", "I-19", 
"I-175"), class = "factor"), Age = c(0L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 
0L, 0L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 22L, 0L, 2L, 11L, 29L, 12L, 
14L, 16L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 7L, 12L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 
6L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 18L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 13L, 11L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 4L, 11L, 
0L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 0L, 18L, 2L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 2L, 
4L, 14L, 6L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 
2L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 1L, 0L, 13L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 2L, 20L, 
10L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 14L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 5L, 20L, 2L, 0L, 12L, 10L, 
1L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 8L, 20L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 21L, 7L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 20L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 10L, 
0L, 0L, 10L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 4L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 1L, 6L, 25L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), capAge = c(0.7, 1.7, 7.7, 8.8, 11.8, 3.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 7.8, 9.8, 2.7, 5.7, 0.7, 0.8, 12.7, 22.7, 0.8, 2.7, 11.7, 
29.8, 12.7, 14.7, 16.7, 13.8, 11.7, 16.7, 0.8, 2.7, 0.7, 7.7, 
12.7, 7.7, 1.8, 2.7, 7.7, 6.7, 3.7, 1.7, 0.8, 0.7, 18.7, 7.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 10.8, 10.7, 10.7, 0.8, 18.7, 1.7, 3.7, 1.7, 0.7, 11.7, 
16.8, 9.7, 9.8, 5.7, 13.8, 11.8, 2.7, 0.8, 0.8, 4.7, 5.7, 6.7, 
5.7, 9.7, 7.7, 0.8, 6.7, 3.8, 5.8, 4.7, 8.8, 0.7, 8.7, 4.8, 11.8, 
0.8, 3.8, 4.7, 12.8, 0.7, 18.7, 2.7, 0.8, 15.7, 0.7, 5.8, 1.7, 
2.7, 5.8, 3.7, 6.7, 1.7, 0.8, 3.7, 4.8, 0.7, 0.7, 5.8, 1.7, 4.7, 
7.8, 12.7, 9.7, 7.7, 2.8, 4.7, 14.7, 6.7, 15.8, 2.7, 7.8, 8.8, 
15.8, 2.7, 7.7, 2.7, 11.7, 9.7, 8.8, 4.8, 2.7, 0.8, 5.8, 0.7, 
4.7, 4.7, 17.8, 1.7, 0.7, 13.7, 8.8, 10.7, 7.7, 2.7, 20.7, 10.7, 
0.8, 6.7, 2.7, 14.7, 8.8, 7.7, 12.7, 5.8, 20.7, 2.7, 0.8, 12.7, 
10.8, 1.8, 13.8, 10.7, 11.8, 1.7, 8.8, 20.7, 9.7, 7.8, 0.7, 1.7, 
4.7, 21.8, 7.8, 4.7, 1.7, 5.7, 8.7, 10.7, 10.8, 9.7, 20.8, 9.8, 
1.7, 4.7, 7.7, 11.7, 10.8, 0.8, 0.7, 10.7, 7.8, 0.8, 0.7, 19.8, 
4.7, 8.7, 0.7, 0.7, 19.7, 1.7, 6.8, 25.8, 0.7, 1.8, 1.7, 0.7), 
    Time = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("P1", 
    "P2"), class = "factor"), Measure = c(21, 29.7, 35.2, 34.5, 
    34.8, 34.3, 23.8, 23.1, 34.8, 35.9, 30.5, 32.4, 21.4, 18.4, 
    35.9, 34.1, 21.9, 29.5, 36.7, 35.7, 33.8, 35, 32.8, 34.3, 
    34.8, 34, 21.4, 32.2, 22.6, 35.2, 34.7, 35, 29.1, 32.2, 32.2, 
    34.8, 32.8, 27.9, 18.6, 22.4, 34.1, 34.5, 22.2, 22.6, 34.5, 
    35, 34.3, 21, 35.2, 30.3, 32.4, 27.2, 21.6, 34.5, 35.2, 34.1, 
    34.7, 34.7, 35, 35, 30.9, 22.4, 22.8, 32.9, 34.3, 33.3, 33.3, 
    33.8, 34.7, 20.5, 35, 32.4, 35, 34.1, 34.5, 21.2, 34.8, 33.8, 
    35.2, 19.7, 32.2, 32.2, 35, 22.6, 34.3, 29.7, 22.4, 35, 22.6, 
    34.7, 28.8, 30.7, 34.1, 33.4, 35.7, 26.9, 22.6, 31.6, 32.4, 
    22.4, 24.5, 33.6, 27.8, 32.1, 34.7, 33.4, 32.9, 34.1, 29.5, 
    31.6, 32.9, 34, 35, 31.6, 35, 33.1, 34.8, 31.2, 34, 29.1, 
    33.8, 34.3, 32.6, 33.3, 31.7, 21, 35.3, 21.6, 34.1, 34, 34.3, 
    27.1, 20.2, 33.6, 34.8, 35.2, 34.8, 31.6, 33.4, 34.7, 21.4, 
    34.5, 32.2, 33.4, 34.5, 32.8, 33.6, 34.5, 35.7, 30.5, 22.4, 
    35.3, 33.8, 29.3, 34.3, 34.1, 35, 28.1, 35.3, 33.3, 34.5, 
    34.1, 21.7, 29.1, 33.4, 35, 33.4, 33.1, 27.9, 34.7, 34.3, 
    34.8, 33.4, 34.3, 36, 34.8, 28.6, 32.6, 34.7, 34.3, 33.3, 
    21.2, 20.2, 34.3, 34.8, 22.1, 19.8, 35, 34.7, 34, 22.1, 20.7, 
    37.4, 28.8, 35.9, 35.2, 20.9, 30.2, 28.8, 21.7), Age2 = c(0.7, 
    1.7, 7.7, 8.7, 11.7, 3.7, 0.7, 0.7, 7.7, 9.7, 2.7, 5.7, 0.7, 
    0.7, 12.7, 22.7, 0.7, 2.7, 11.7, 29.7, 12.7, 14.7, 16.7, 
    13.7, 11.7, 16.7, 0.7, 2.7, 0.7, 7.7, 12.7, 7.7, 1.7, 2.7, 
    7.7, 6.7, 3.7, 1.7, 0.7, 0.7, 18.7, 7.7, 0.7, 0.7, 10.7, 
    10.7, 10.7, 0.7, 18.7, 1.7, 3.7, 1.7, 0.7, 11.7, 16.7, 9.7, 
    9.7, 5.7, 13.7, 11.7, 2.7, 0.7, 0.7, 4.7, 5.7, 6.7, 5.7, 
    9.7, 7.7, 0.7, 6.7, 3.7, 5.7, 4.7, 8.7, 0.7, 8.7, 4.7, 11.7, 
    0.7, 3.7, 4.7, 12.7, 0.7, 18.7, 2.7, 0.7, 15.7, 0.7, 5.7, 
    1.7, 2.7, 5.7, 3.7, 6.7, 1.7, 0.7, 3.7, 4.7, 0.7, 0.7, 5.7, 
    1.7, 4.7, 7.7, 12.7, 9.7, 7.7, 2.7, 4.7, 14.7, 6.7, 15.7, 
    2.7, 7.7, 8.7, 15.7, 2.7, 7.7, 2.7, 11.7, 9.7, 8.7, 4.7, 
    2.7, 0.7, 5.7, 0.7, 4.7, 4.7, 17.7, 1.7, 0.7, 13.7, 8.7, 
    10.7, 7.7, 2.7, 20.7, 10.7, 0.7, 6.7, 2.7, 14.7, 8.7, 7.7, 
    12.7, 5.7, 20.7, 2.7, 0.7, 12.7, 10.7, 1.7, 13.7, 10.7, 11.7, 
    1.7, 8.7, 20.7, 9.7, 7.7, 0.7, 1.7, 4.7, 21.7, 7.7, 4.7, 
    1.7, 5.7, 8.7, 10.7, 10.7, 9.7, 20.7, 9.7, 1.7, 4.7, 7.7, 
    11.7, 10.7, 0.7, 0.7, 10.7, 7.7, 0.7, 0.7, 19.7, 4.7, 8.7, 
    0.7, 0.7, 19.7, 1.7, 6.7, 25.7, 0.7, 1.7, 1.7, 0.7)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Age", "capAge", "Time", "Measure", "Age2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), formula = Measure ~ Age | ID, FUN = function (x) 
max(x, na.rm = TRUE), order.groups = TRUE, class = c("nfnGroupedData", 
"nfGroupedData", "groupedData", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: To whom It may concern: at first sight it may appear that this question is off-topic as it focuses at usage of nlme R package, but the question seems to focus rather on statistical modeling and as such is perfectly **on-topic**.